# PHP file require failure

Tags: php

Here is my directory structure for let you know(i consider affection folder only)

**PostsHandling -**

- uploadimage.php
- controller.php
- a.html
- jQuery-2.1.4.min.js

**PostsHandling** file located in a localhost folder and so when i call **a.html** file from my browser, it requests for **uploadimage.php** by javascript AJAX automatically. Please see **uploadimage.php** file which contain

```
<?php

  require_once '../../note.php';
  //more codes
?>
```

This is my **a.html** file codes

```
<html>
<head>
<script src ="jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


    $.ajax({

        url : "uploadimage.php",

        type : "POST",

        success : function(data){

            $('body').append(data)
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
```

This says

> Warning: require_once(../note.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\note\api\PostsHandling\controller.php on line 12
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../note.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\note\api\PostsHandling\controller.php on line 12

But i called this **uploadimage.php** file individually. there are no any error. because it was just a blank page! why i got this error?

Your reply and response is highly appreciated!

Comment: The note.php file is in the same directory as the uploadimage.php file, so you need to remove the directory includes from it, no?

Comment: Oh... I see the error. No need to answer

Comment: @SGrimminck Thank you!